# Is it possible to make --word-diff default in git diff, git gui, gitk

Tags: git, git-diff, git-config, word-diff

Is it possible to set an option that git diff is always using `--word-diff=color` whenever displaying diffs?

I know that there are command line arguments for gitk, git-gui and git diff, but are there config options I can set globally?

I found that this works for git-gui:
Adding this to .gitconfig works for guid

```
[gui]
    diffopts = --word-diff --color-words
```

But using this, I can not actually pick anything anymore. I get "diff fails to apply" whenever I want to commit any line or chunk.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but if you install diff-so-fancy it does that for you in a different and I'd say a better way. It doesn't use the Git word diff functionality, but figures out the changed characters itself and highlights them - https://github.com/so-fancy/diff-so-fancy

Answer (score 15):

If you frequently invoke `git diff` you may define a git alias.

```
$ git config [--global] alias.df "diff --word-diff=color"
```

And then use `git df` instead of `git diff`.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the options you want to use in git gui with `gui.diffopts`. For example, for word diff:

```
git config --global gui.diffopts --word-diff
```

Comment: This does not work, it will break the git gui, at least select the lines to stage does not work, see this discussion: [linux - Using diff-highlight with Git GUI - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/933872/using-diff-highlight-with-git-gui)

Comment: There is an issue in the `git-gui`'s github source repo, see here: [Visualization of intraline differences](https://github.com/prati0100/git-gui/issues/31)

Comment: @Jonah Graham do you realize you're precisely doing the exact same thing that OP already mentioned from their `.gitconfig`. You're not bringing any new information to this thread. Please read the question you're trying to answer entirely before doing so.

Comment: @adamency please read the question, answer, edits and notice the differences. Welcome to SO!