# How can I make git diff always use the --word-diff option?

Tags: git, terminal, diff, configuration-files, git-config

What do I have to write in the `.gitconfig` file in order for `git diff` to behave as it was `git diff --word-diff`?

For now, searching for `\bword` in `man git-config` I've found `diff.wordRegex`, and given that

> The name is actually the section and the key separated by a dot

from the same man page, I've verified that

```
[diff]
  wordRegex = some-regex
```

affects the diff when I run `git diff --word-diff`. For instance, `wordRegex = "."` causes a character-wise diff.

But how do I tell `git` to always use `--word-diff` (or `--color-words`, fwiw)?

---

I know aliases exist, and I use some, but I was curious if there's an option.

---

Of the two answers [at a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32831437/is-it-possible-to-make-word-diff-default-in-git-diff-git-gui-gitk),

- [the first one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41511903/5825294) suggests to use an alias, which is not what I'm looking for, as written above;
- [the second one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58613364/5825294) is about GUI, which I'm not interested into either.

Comment: Would an alias work? `git config --global alias.diff "diff --word-diff"`. FWIW, I use the alias name `wd` for this.

Comment: @wjandrea: You can't alias an actual Git command (because Git would then get stuck in an endless expansion loop, which is a silly reason, but that's the reason). Using `git wd` is the way to go.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to make --word-diff default in git diff, git gui, gitk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32831437/is-it-possible-to-make-word-diff-default-in-git-diff-git-gui-gitk)

Comment: @Joe, no it doesn't, as per my edit. I've also added a tag to clarify even better.